# Skewing/rotating a plot in matplotlib.Basemap

Tags: python, basemap, matplotlib

I am currently plotting data onto an orthographic projection in matplotlib's Basemap. I would like to rotate or skew the plot to a 23.5 degree angle, corresponding to the Earth's axial tilt.

The map I am using is

```
`map = Basemap(projection='ortho',lon_0=-45,lat_0=30,resolution='l')`
```

Comment: proj4 could do this, but I don't know how to do it in Python.